# block.io alternative?

Tags: alternatives, block.io

Hi is there a alternative service to block.io Unfortunately they are not allowing mainet wallet on developer api and their monthly cost is too high. So looking for an alternative?

I want to use online service to have wallets online, that can send payments using api

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/api) api, they are free and fairly good to start sending Cryptos and creating wallets.
But if your business grows you will need either create your own blockchain provider alongside with your own full node or pay for a service like block.io

Answer (score 0):

I believe Coinbase provides all of the functionality you mentioned as far as online wallets with developer APIs. Their documentation can be found here: https://developers.coinbase.com/